# @react-pdf/renderer on production gives an error this.subset.encodeStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pdf, webpack

**@react-pdf/renderer stopped working on the production machine, everything is fine on the local machine.**

I don't know how to find a solution for this problem online

What can this error be related to? I will be very grateful for your help

This library worked on the site for more than a year, but now it has stopped. The site is written in laravel 9 with react

"@react-pdf/renderer": "2.0.19"

[image]

Comment: `ReactPDF.render()` is a Node-only API to save pdfs in disk. You are using this lib in a web environment so this method won't be available. Check this issue : https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/341

Comment: I am getting the same error when trying to use a registered font.

Answer (score 9):

Delete Font.register({}) and use some default font from [documentation](https://react-pdf.org/fonts) or install the latest version react-pdf/renderer.

npm i @react-pdf/renderer@latest

For me work fine.

Comment: After update works me. Even twith Font.register

Comment: Can CONFIRM this works! - Thanks!

Comment: After install the last version it worked for me.